# How do I use Do While to stop a loop?

Tags: c, loops

I am writing a simple program that takes an input and adds it to a sum and then prints it, but then asks for another input and also adds that to the sum. However when 0 is in the input, the program should stop. That part is not working, here is what I have tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

int n, summa, t;

summa = 0;
t=1;
do{
scanf("%d", &n);
if(n==0){t=0;
}
summa = n + summa;


printf("%d\n", summa);

}
while(t == 0);{return 0;}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Where are you asking for another input?

Comment: You are looking for `break`; it will work in any loop. Check the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: Formatting and indentation will make your program *much* easier to read and understand. Please [edit] your question to properly indent your code.

Comment: I also recommend you try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with the code you have. When will the loop really exit?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow When the loop restarts it scans for another number.

Comment: @Neil  So where sould i put break statement? As the execution for the while statement instead of return 0;?

Comment: Sort of `do { int r = scanf(" %d", &n); if(r == EOF) { /*check for error?*/; break; } else if(r == 0) { /*throw out the line*/getline(); continue; } else if(n == 0) { break; } printf("%d\n", summa = n + summa); } while(1);`. This will not print out an extra line at the end.

Comment: Relevant from the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and [a beginner's guide](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you intended your conditional to be `t != 0`.

Here's a reformatted version of your code with the new conditional, see if that functions as you expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, summa, t;
    summa = 0;
    t = 1;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n == 0) {
            t = 0;
        }

        summa = n + summa;
        printf("%d\n", summa);
    }
    while(t != 0);

    return 0;
}
```